# PCIe Endpoint to System Memory /Endpoint Transaction

Tags: linux, memory, pci-express

I have PCIe Endpoint & Root Complex will be PC running linux.Now, I want to send few bytes(say, 4 bytes) from EP to system memory (RC) using PCIe Memory Read Request (TLP) Example of PCIe Memory TLP .

[image: Memory Request TLP]

---

For sending this , an EP needs to know the address  of system memory.
As far as I understand, RC will be connected to system memory so any transaction targeting RC will be targeting system memory so an EP should know the address range of RC.Here is the sample image:

[image: EP to System memory transaction]

**My questions:**

1. How does an EP know the address of system memory? Is RC BAR mapped to system memory? If yes, can an EP access RC BAR? If yes,how?
2. Similarly, when an EP wants to communicate with another EP , it should know target EP BAR address.So,how does an EP know the address of
       another EP?

   Sample image :[image: EP to EP Memory Transaction]
3. Is there any linux code/driver which I could refer for EP to System-memory / another EP communication?

---

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: Haven't you asked this before? At least I remember a very similar question. The answer is still: You don't just send EP requests "to read memory". That request has some purpose. You must tell us what the purpose is. Usually the purpose will involve a driver on the PC side, and this driver will reserve memory as a communication area, and it will tell your hardware the physical address of the memory for DMA etc. And no, the BAR is never mapped to PC memory.

Comment: Yes, the question is very much similar but this one is more elaborated. The purpose is just to do data transfer from EP to PC(RC). So, does it mean that RC driver on linux side will provide api for getting physical address of the memory for DMA which could be used by an EP ? If yes, could you help me to locate that api? Sorry, I am just a beginner in linux.

Comment: You can't "just do data transfer". If you "just want to do data transfer", put the data somewhere in the address range of the BARs, and have the *PC* issue a read/write request to the endpoint. This will transfer data from/to your device. That works even without a driver, IIRC somewhere in /proc or /sys there's a "file" representing the BAR areas.

Comment: Thanks a lot, dirkt for the answer. I believe you have provided  possible solutions to one of my problems. For second question regarding EP to EP communication, how will this be handled? Will it be something like this: put data somewhere in the address range of one of BARs of one EP & then to transfer it to another EP, have PC issue read/write to another endpoint respective BAR?